# How to Make Two Vertical Line in Same row using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make a two vertical line in the same row using CSS.

I want to create like this :
[image: Example Screenshot]

I have already added one vertical thick line (Refer below script )

```
.desg {
border-bottom: 2px solid LightSlateGrey;
border-left: 15px solid LightSlateGrey ; 
background-color: white;
font-size: 20px;
font-family:"ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3", "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro",Osaka, "メイリオ", Meiryo, "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック", "MS PGothic", sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
color: #778899; }
```

Answer (score 5):

What I would recommend is to make use of the [**`:before`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo-selector. You'll want to make the element **itself** the narrow line, as the `:before` will appear to the **right** of `border-left`. Then make the `:before` the thick line.

You can even add a bit of `margin` on either side:

```css
.desg {
  border-bottom: 2px solid LightSlateGrey;
  border-left: 3px solid LightSlateGrey;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3", "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro", Osaka, "メイリオ", Meiryo, "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック", "MS PGothic", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #778899;
}

.desg:before {
  border-left: 15px solid LightSlateGrey;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="desg">Text</div>
```

Remember that in order for the border in `:before` to appear, you'll need to give `:before` a **`content`** property, which can be left empty.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Or :after pseudo class with little modifications

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using border for something like this I'd go with using`<hr>`or `div` tag.
While using `<hr>` you'd need to set border width and while using `div` you can use `width` or `border`. Will provide code shortly or you can go without `:before`pseudo class